# Fire Deparment Response to a Wizard Duel

Tags: earth, modern-age, fire

In Modern Suburban America, two wizards have a duel using only a beginner fireball spell at 3 am. They both have really bad aim.

The local authorities are alerted and arrive in less than 5 minutes. The wizards disappear when the authorities arrive, but by then ~20 ignition points have been lit.

For ease of answering, we can make the following assumptions:

1. The fire works like a normal fire.
2. The fire department does not have access to magic.
3. There is a history of fires in this neighborhood.
4. All blazes are located within 2 square blocks.
5. Houses are all made of brick, and have the US average lawn size of average 10,000 square feet (929 square meters). It is autumn and several houses have dried leaves on the the ground.
6. All ignition points are miraculously located outside of homes, involving trees, bushes, piles of leaves, and other vegetation. And exactly one burning dumpster.
7. It has been less than 5 minutes since the first fire occurred. All other fires started between 1-4 minutes ago.
8. No houses are currently on fire, but several have their yards on fire.
9. It is 3 am, many residents are sleeping.
10. There are 10 separate houses on the street with their yards on fire, and an additional 20 adjacent to at least one of those 10.
11. Three to five trucks arrive on the scene as the first responders.

Assuming the fire department is going to want to quarantine the area, evacuate the any resents in danger, and begin putting out fires (or just letting them burn). What will the firefighters prioritize doing within the first 5 minutes?

Comment: Do magic fires act differently to normal fires and will the fire department be able to tell that these fires aren't normal fires?

Comment: By "Modern Suburban America" do you actually mean reality or does your setting include other magic users?

Comment: For ease of answering, we can assume the fires work like normal fires, and the world follows the usual Urbran Fantasy tropes of most local authorities being unable to use magic and unaware of the magical realm.

Comment: Could you edit that into the question, there's a risk people won't read the comments or the comments will be deleted.

Comment: We need *way* more details before we can answer this.  How many homes? How large is the neighborhood? How many people live there? How large are the fires at the time they show up? How spread apart are the ignition points? Are the ignition points inside houses, on lawns, in cars?  Are there any reports of people or animals trapped in a fire? Is it night or day?  All these things (and more) drastically change how a modern fire department would respond to such a fire.

Comment: You'll have to narrow this down quite a bit - perhaps try asking about a specific situation, or a specific response of the fire department (such as *how do they prioritize ignition points?*, or *when do they focus on containment instead of preservation of property?*)

Comment: They'll just call in enough reinforcements to deal with the many simultaneous fires, and proceed as usual. And, once they are done, they'll call in one hell of an investigation to answer the question just how so many fires could be lit in so short a timeframe. Unless they panic at the initial sight of the many simultaneous fires, thinking it's a terrorist attack, and stay clear of the area for fear of a secondary blast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This answer is just creative speculation.  I am not a firefighter.*

The answer depends on the needs of your story.  If you want to show the fireman leadership to be experienced and competent, then they will prioritize which fires to fight first based on each fire's proximity to other combustibles while accounting for wind speed and direction.  Both hoses and portable extinguishers will be used to maximize the number of flash-points which the available crew can address simultaneously.

If an immediate victory against the flames is not likely, the firefighters will focus on wetting down fire-adjacent combustibles to create breaks and barriers which will hopefully contain the flames.

If the neighborhood has hydrants they will hook up to them for an unlimited water supply.  If not, they will order more tanker engines and refill trucks if such things exist.  Nearby fire stations may be called to add crew and equipment to the fight.

They will call in police and medical first responders to handle the evacuation process, so that their fighters can stay focused on the flames.  Sleeping house residents shouldn't be much of a problem with all those different sirens screaming at once.

Since you are the author, you are free to limit the scenario to events which reinforce the wisdom of whatever choices your fighter fighters make.  Or if your story's goal is to have the fire overwhelm the mundane attempts to handle it, you can undermine the applied wisdom.  Fire is apparently a very tricky adversary...  Your story can use it to change direction in a number of exciting yet believable ways.

*Afterthought...*  This is also a great opportunity to demonstrate the interaction between the magical and mundane worlds.  If one of your responders recognizes the source and nature of the blaze, they might step aside to make a private cellphone call to a local weather-witch, requesting a heavy rain storm.  Then after the danger passes, another phone call to the magical authorities to start an investigation.  Your wizards be in for some nasty consequences for their ill-placed little duel.